# How/When do views generate columns

Tags: postgresql

Consider the following setup:

```sql
CREATE TABLE person (
  first_name varchar,
  last_name varchar,
  age INT
 );
 
INSERT INTO person (first_name, last_name, age)
VALUES ('pete', 'peterson', 16),
        ('john', 'johnson', 20),
        ('dick', 'dickson', 42),
        ('rob', 'robson', 30);
 
Create OR REPLACE VIEW adult_view AS
SELECT 
  first_name || ' ' || last_name as full_name, 
  age
FROM person;
```

If I run:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM adult_view
WHERE age > 18;
```

Will the view generate the `full_name` column for `pete` even though he gets filtered out?

Similarly, if I run:

```sql
SELECT age
FROM adult_view;
```

Will the view generate any `full_name` columns at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Concerning your first query:

```
EXPLAIN (VERBOSE, COSTS OFF)
SELECT full_name
FROM adult_view
WHERE age > 18;
                                    QUERY PLAN                                    
══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
 Seq Scan on laurenz.person
   Output: (((person.first_name)::text || ' '::text) || (person.last_name)::text)
   Filter: (person.age > 18)
 Query Identifier: 5675263059379476127
```

So the table is scanned, people under 19 are filtered out, and then the result is calculated. So `full_name` won't be computed for Pete.

#### Concerning your second query:

```
EXPLAIN (VERBOSE, COSTS OFF)
SELECT age       
FROM adult_view
WHERE age > 18;
               QUERY PLAN               
════════════════════════════════════════
 Seq Scan on laurenz.person
   Output: person.age
   Filter: (person.age > 18)
 Query Identifier: -8981994317495194105
(4 rows)
```

`full_name` is not calculated at all.

Comment: That's awesome! How was it generated?

Comment: I showed it in my answer: with `EXPLAIN`.